# DukTape Display JavaScript Canvas on GLUT Window

Tags: javascript, c++, canvas, graphics, duktape

I managed to get DukTape working in my GLUT project (it is able to run inline javascript with duk_eval_string();).  Is it possible to display a static html canvas with javascript graphics in a C++ GLUT window using DukTape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the HTML5 canvas drawing methods is not possible in Duktape.
Duktape is a Javascript engine, what means that it allows you to execute ES5/5.1 compliant code. Displaying a HTML canvas is a task Duktape can't do.

If you ultimately want to achieve this, try searching for a library to achieve such a task, maybe look at the Firefox source.
If you want to do it completely from scratch you would need to add *C function bindings* (Example at duktape.org/) for every draw method you want. An example would be like this:

```
// C/C++ code:
// C function to be used in the Javascript engine 
int js_draw_rect(duk_context *ctx) {
    // get parameters from javascript function call
    int pos_x = duk_get_number(ctx, -4);
    int pos_y = duk_get_number(ctx, -3);
    ...

    // C/C++ code to draw the rectangle (in your case probably GLUT)
    draw_rectangle(pos_x, pos_y, ...);
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    duk_context *ctx;
    ...

    // this snippet adds a binding for the function 'js_draw_rect' so it can be called from Javascript code
    duk_push_global_object(ctx);
    duk_push_c_function(ctx, js_draw_rect, 4/*number of args the JS function has*/);
    duk_put_prop_string(ctx, -2 /*idx:global*/, "drawRect"/*name of function in JS environment*/);
    duk_pop(ctx);
}

// Javascript code:
drawRect(50, 50, 100, 200);
...
```

This method allows you to create C/C++ functions which handle all drawing and later bind them all to the Javascript engine so they can be called in JS.